# Redirecting traffic on Windows Phone 8(.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

We are looking for a way to programatically intercept global network traffic on **Windows Phone 8** or **Windows Phone 8.1**.

I currently know two ways to intercept traffic:

- Proxy server
- VPN *(proprietary network, where all traffic is routed through a specific server)*

On both Android and iOS we use a proxy server. On Android we use specific manufacturer SDK's to set proxy configuration and on iOS install a proxy profile.

*We wish to implement the same functionality on Windows Phone 8 and newer.*

According to my research, **Windows Runtime supports proxy configurations in code** with [`Windows.Networking.Connectivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx) namespace. But according to the documentation, working with `ProxyConfiguration` class, the code throws `NotImplementedException` on **Windows Phone 8**.

The `Windows.Networking.Vpn` namespace is also not available on **Windows Phone 8**.

So apparently, both options are out here.

My first question is:

**Is there any other way I could intercept and redirect traffic on Windows Phone 8?**

*Further research:*

According to the documentation of newly released **Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Preview**, there are some changes in those namespaces. At least `Windows.Networking.Vpn` is now available, I am not yet sure for `ProxyConfiguration` class.

**Is there any sample code or examples available on whether either proxy configuration or setting VPN programatically is possible with Windows Phone 8.1 SDK?**

*I also cannot seem to find the correctly updated documentation for the newest SDK yet.*

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like what you want can only be done by the OEM. [Windows Phone Connectivity configuration](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Connectivity_configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports the `ProxyConfiguration` class, BUT it is ment to get readonly info about the set proxies. So this is not a way to set a proxy in Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: I am aware of that. Is it possible to get Proxy information based on that API?

Comment: @Legoless Yes, it is possible.